# Can an app in Google TV Honeycomb access remote functions, such as turning on the Television

Tags: google-tv

I've got an idea for a tool I would like to make for Google TV once honeycomb + market lands on it, but it would function worlds better if I could also turn on the TV rather than having to make the user do it themselves

My idea is simple: Schedule your favourite shows, tv turns on, activates the STB then tunes to the proper channel when the show starts.

For reference  I would be devving this on a Revue, which I know has the IR blaster and such needed to send the remote signals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that and more using the [Anymote Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/).  For sample code, take a look at the source of the [Google TV Remote](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.tvremote) app: http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/

Comment: This can be used locally from the Revue itself, or would I be better off making myself a service on my home server box?

Comment: If you want to run something locally, then the first step might actually be the AlarmManager.  Integration with the power controls may be limited to some OEMs, but should work on some.

It sounds like the AnymoteProtocol is actually overkill unless you're building the app on separate device that you want to "remote control" the TV.

Answer (score -1):

If you can control the IR device, then turning on the TV should be a snap.  Additionally, some newer TVs have an HDMI functionality that lets you turn it on using it; however, not all TVs support this.  All TVs do support infrared, though.

You'd want to look for "System Standby" here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi#CEC

The TV would have to technically be in its "sleep" mode for the device to turn it on, similar to how PC monitors work.

Comment: The question was more if the non-rooted APIs support sending generic commands like this ( Since the Revue already knows the model TV and STB, it can already send these signals through user input) The question becomes less if it's technically possible ( Yes ) but if it will be possible through the APIs provided to us.